# Query Planner not using GIST index in the presence of `count` or `order by`

Tags: postgresql

The following query looks a bit complex but actually simply selects an XML column using a filter on a GIST index and ordering by another 'XML field' which is also indexed.

```
Explain(analyze, buffers) Select
                content::text ,
                count(*) over()
            from B2HEAD.item
            where cluster = 'B2BOX' and 
            (  
                 ( concept=$b2$Test$b2$ )  and  
                 ( to_tsvector('english', array_to_string_i(xpath('/Test/BusinessDocNumber//text()', content)::text[], ' ')) @@ to_tsquery('english', 'MNJ4989') )  
            ) 
            order by  (array_to_string_i(xpath('/Test/CreationDate//text()', content)::text[], ' ')::varchar(256)) desc 
            offset 0 limit 50;
```

The query is slow and only the index on the ordered field is used (`item_mi_idx01`)

```
 Limit  (cost=0.43..6721.92 rows=50 width=997) (actual time=70038.645..70038.647 rows=1 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=418875 read=435292
   ->  WindowAgg  (cost=0.43..784801.69 rows=5838 width=997) (actual time=70038.642..70038.642 rows=1 loops=1)
         Buffers: shared hit=418875 read=435292
         ->  Index Scan Backward using item_mi_idx01 on item  (cost=0.43..783240.03 rows=5838 width=997) (actual time=1.610..70038.487 rows=1 loops=1)
               Filter: (to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, array_to_string_i((xpath('/Test/BusinessDocNumber//text()'::text, content, '{}'::text[]))::text[], ' '::text)) @@ '''mnj4989'''::tsquery)
               Rows Removed by Filter: 1389827
               Buffers: shared hit=418875 read=435292
 Planning time: 8.939 ms
 Execution time: 70038.803 ms
(10 rows)
```

Removing the `Order By` clause however, leads to the use of the GIST index (`item_mi_fts_idx04`) and is a very fast query

```
Limit  (cost=0.29..51.70 rows=50 width=997) (actual time=13.971..13.974 rows=1 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared read=1011
  ->  WindowAgg  (cost=0.29..6003.62 rows=5838 width=997) (actual time=13.969..13.970 rows=1 loops=1)
        Buffers: shared read=1011
        ->  Index Scan using item_mi_fts_idx04 on item  (cost=0.29..5930.64 rows=5838 width=997) (actual time=6.838..13.958 rows=1 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, array_to_string_i((xpath('/Test/BusinessDocNumber//text()'::text, content, '{}'::text[]))::text[], ' '::text)) @@ '''mnj4989'''::tsquery)
              Buffers: shared read=1011
Planning time: 9.120 ms
Execution time: 14.044 ms
(9 rows)
```

Same story if keeping the `Order By` and removing the `count(*) over()` in the `select`

```
Limit  (cost=7613.27..7613.39 rows=50 width=997) (actual time=12.362..12.362 rows=1 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=1014
  ->  Sort  (cost=7613.27..7627.86 rows=5838 width=997) (actual time=12.359..12.359 rows=1 loops=1)
        Sort Key: ((array_to_string_i((xpath('/Test/CreationDate//text()'::text, content, '{}'::text[]))::text[], ' '::text))::character varying(256)) DESC
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 27kB
        Buffers: shared hit=1014
        ->  Index Scan using item_mi_fts_idx04 on item  (cost=0.29..7419.33 rows=5838 width=997) (actual time=5.863..12.333 rows=1 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, array_to_string_i((xpath('/Test/BusinessDocNumber//text()'::text, content, '{}'::text[]))::text[], ' '::text)) @@ '''mnj4989'''::tsquery)
              Buffers: shared hit=1011
Planning time: 8.201 ms
Execution time: 12.417 ms
(11 rows)
```

These queries are auto-generated and we need to keep both the `count` and the `order by`.

What can be done to tell PostgreSQL to make use of the GIST index ?

(Vacuum analyze has been run on the table)

---

**EDIT** (following @a_horse_with_no_name comment)

The rewritten query now looks like

```
Explain(analyze,buffers)
    With data as (
     Select
                    content::text ,
                    (array_to_string_i(xpath('/Test/CreationDate//text()', content)::text[], ' ')::varchar(256)) as orderField,
                    count(*) over()
                from B2HEAD.item
                where cluster = 'B2BOX'
                      and concept=$b2$Test$b2$
                      and to_tsvector('english', array_to_string_i(xpath('/Test/BusinessDocNumber//text()', content)::text[], ' ')) @@ to_tsquery('english', 'MJ')
    )
    select * from data
    order by  data.orderField desc
    offset 0 limit 50;
```

This makes use of the GIST index (`item_mi_fts_idx04`) and is much faster

```
  Limit  (cost=7803.00..7803.13 rows=50 width=556) (actual time=12.928..12.928 rows=0 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=3 read=963
  CTE data
    ->  WindowAgg  (cost=0.29..7492.31 rows=5838 width=997) (actual time=12.908..12.908 rows=0 loops=1)
          Buffers: shared read=963
          ->  Index Scan using item_mi_fts_idx04 on item  (cost=0.29..5930.64 rows=5838 width=997) (actual time=12.903..12.903 rows=0 loops=1)
                Index Cond: (to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, array_to_string_i((xpath('/Test/BusinessDocNumber//text()'::text, content, '{}'::text[]))::text[], ' '::text)) @@ '''mj'''::tsquery)
                Buffers: shared read=963
  ->  Sort  (cost=310.69..325.29 rows=5838 width=556) (actual time=12.926..12.926 rows=0 loops=1)
        Sort Key: data.orderfield DESC
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
        Buffers: shared hit=3 read=963
        ->  CTE Scan on data  (cost=0.00..116.76 rows=5838 width=556) (actual time=12.909..12.909 rows=0 loops=1)
              Buffers: shared read=963
Planning time: 9.335 ms
Execution time: 13.015 ms
(16 rows)
```

However the sort is now a quick sort, which is fast over 6000 rows, but which performance degrades pretty fast (O(n log n)) with an increasing number of rows (for 1M rows, the query will take over a minute).

Using a CTE, we could not find a way to make PostgreSQL to use the BTREE index `item_mi_idx01` which indexes data pointed to by the `data.OrderField`

Further help would be appreciated.

Here is another attempt, which will also use a quick sort, even if the condition on the plain text search is removed...

```
Explain(analyze,buffers)
With data as (
    Select
        content::text as xml
    from B2HEAD.item
    where cluster = 'B2BOX'
          and concept=$b2$Test$b2$
          and to_tsvector('english', array_to_string_i(xpath('/Test/BusinessDocNumber//text()', content)::text[], ' ')) @@ to_tsquery('english', 'Aggregated')
    order by (array_to_string_i(xpath('/Test/CreationDate//text()', content)::text[], ' ')::varchar(256)) desc
)
select xml, count(*) over() from data
offset 0 limit 50;
```

**EDIT 2**

`count(*) over()` seems to be the source of all issues. Removing it in any of the queries above will lead to fast queries.

Working on [estimates](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Count_estimate); will keep this page updated.

**WE GIVE UP !**

Changing the limit of the first query above, changes the behaviour!
Increasing the limit has the query using the GIST index, even when the query actually returns a single value.

There are too many moving parts in the Query Planner to attempt to program anything around it; we will just attempt to trick it..

Comment: Try wrapping the query (without an order by) in a CTE and then order the result of the CTE: `with data as (select ..., to_tsvector(..) as content from ... where ...) select * from data order by content`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you and my apologies for the late reply. See Edit above. TD; LR; This makes use of the GIST index but how can we *also* benefit from the BTREE index for the sort ?